# Shared Google map doesn't show all locations from original map

Tags: google-maps

I have googled a select number of locations for a business and was attempting to share the resulting map on a webpage. However using either the share link or the iframe embed code looses two of the locations, even though they're still in the url query string.

Is this because it's not designed to show multiple locations in this way (I normally use the API or My maps) so behaviour can't be guaranteed? I only attempted this way as there is another map on the page already embedded in this manner with two locations (which display fine). Wondering if perhaps three is the limit or something...?

The screenshot shows the map with the five locations while the share link and iframe embed below only show three of the five.

[Google map screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsqgH.jpg)

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/BH+Live+corfe+mullen+pelhams+stokewood+queens+park+littledowne/@50.7485805,-1.9350838,12z

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d80782.58745900173!2d-1.9350837501421971!3d50.74858048553776!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1sBH+Live+corfe+mullen+pelhams+stokewood+queens+park+littledowne!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1509970891850" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can easily work around this with other solutions but can anybody explain *why* this is happening please?

Comment: I tried replicating it with your query params and it seems that zooming adds a location or two. You can try to do a [Send Feedback](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088) in the Maps web app to report this to the right team as the Google Maps API has differences from the web app.

Comment: I did see that too but only twice for some reason. After that I couldn't replicate it. Thanks for taking a look though, I'll feedback to Google.